# Multi-variable data table in Excel causing it to hang up

Tags: excel

I have 13 long sets of data of different variations of an instrument. For a particular set of parameters (2 parameters - say X collectively), I have a series of formulas that calculate certain outputs (26 outputs - 2 for each data set, say Y collectively) in a table.

Now, I build a new table populated with about 20 sets of all different Xs and all the resultant Ys using a method suggested [here](https://www.mathscinotes.com/2016/10/excel-data-table-with-more-than-two-input-variables/), wherein the INDEX function and the data table feature of Excel are used along with 2 selectors (1 for the parameter set and 1 for the output set) to create desired multi-variable table for a table full of different parameters.

I have used this method a few times before as well without any problems. This time, however, the data tables are too long and each output calculation needs going through all of them using multiple INDEX functions. This is causing Excel to hang up a lot. For a single set of parameters it works just fine. As soon as I try to populate my multi-parameter table, it starts acting up. So bad that my PC almost freezes.

Any suggestion on how can this process be made faster? I had seen some options for multi-variable tables and found this a convenient one. In terms of computational complexity is this not an efficient method and is there another more efficient one?

I tried using Excel Online hoping for Microsoft to use it's own computing power there, but it acts weirdly online - random deletion of cells and stuff. Has anyone had success with Excel Online in such computation issues? (I have Office 365 subscription)

My PC specs:
Intel Core i7 5500U
16GB DDR3 RAM
Windows 10 x64

Let me know if any other information is required. Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: A minimal example is best represented on this page - https://www.mathscinotes.com/2016/10/excel-data-table-with-more-than-two-input-variables/
My own sheet uses exactly the same method except with higher number of parameter sets and output sets and larger amount of data to create output from.

Edit 2: I am attaching a screenshot of my Excel sheet as an attempt to explain my own formulas, as suggested by BigBen. [My Excel sheet's formulas' screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkjYf.jpg)

In the event that the link I posted dies, I am also attaching the image of the [example](https://www.mathscinotes.com/2016/10/excel-data-table-with-more-than-two-input-variables/) that I had previously mentioned. [Mark Biegert of Math Encounters' example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kVRh.jpg)

Comment: I have added the link to a perfect representative example of my own sheet. Basically my sheet faces problem because of larger amount of data that it has to sift through for each output compared to that in the page linked here. My system isn't able to handle it.

Comment: I have edited again to try and give some explanation about my own Excel sheet through a screenshot.